# Как можно скопировать строку в структуру в которой есть поле (массив) строки

Tags: c

Есть у меня структура вида:

```
struct HeaderFile {
char name[20];
char textExtension[4];
uint32_t size;
uint32_t crc;
} HeaderFileList;
```

есть массив строки вида:

```
char *str = "123456789";
```

как можно скопировать строку str в структуру в поле name ?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/strcpy.html)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy):

```
const char* str = "123456789";
HeaderFile obj;

// Скопировать в obj.name не более 20 символов из строки str
strncpy(obj.name, str, 20);

// Установить последний элемент массива нулевым символом, на случай если в str больше 19 символов
obj.name[19] = '\0';
```